# How to use addIssueTokens Utility method in TokenSDK

Tags: corda

i want to use addIssueTokens to  add token to  TransactionBuilder.
my code

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Issue(val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() : SignedTransaction{
        val jpyToken = createFungibleToken("JPY", 1000, otherParty)
        val gbToken = createFungibleToken("GB", 1000, otherParty)
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.single()
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
        //may be add other output input
        //....
        
        //add token to txBuilder
        addIssueTokens(txBuilder, listOf(jpyToken,gbToken))
        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)
        // Sign the transaction
        val ptx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, ourIdentity.owningKey)
        // Instantiate a network session with the shareholder
        val holderSession = initiateFlow(otherParty)
        val sessions = listOf(holderSession)
        // Ask the shareholder to sign the transaction
        val stx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(ptx, listOf(holderSession)))
        return subFlow<SignedTransaction>(FinalityFlow(stx, sessions))
    }
    fun createFungibleToken(symbol:String,amout:Long,target : AbstractParty) : FungibleToken{
        val tokenType = TokenType(symbol, 0)
        val issuedTokenType = IssuedTokenType(ourIdentity, tokenType)
        val amount = Amount<IssuedTokenType>(amout, issuedTokenType)
        return FungibleToken(amount, target)
    }
}
@InitiatedBy(Issue::class)
class IssueResponder(val otherPartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction  {
        val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartySession) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
            }
        }
        val txId = subFlow(signTransactionFlow).id
        return subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartySession, expectedTxId = txId))
    }
}
```

shell: start flow

```
>>start com.template.flows.Issue otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
Starting
Collecting signatures from counterparties.
Starting
Broadcasting transaction to participants
Done
Flow completed with result: SignedTransaction(id=547B812BA5574168DA8085C87AADFCAFA2A098CF62F375C21D450C0FE2402547)
```

it seems that Flow completed. but i check partyB database ,there is no data in vault_states table .

why?

ps.i knew how to use com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows.flows.rpc.IssueTokens flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `holder` is not a required signer when **issuing** tokens; try removing the `CollectSignaturesFlow` and `SignTransactionFlow` calls from the initiator and responder flows; only keep `FinalityFlow` and `ReceiveFinalityFlow`.

You can see [here](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/contracts/FungibleTokenContract.kt) that the required signers are:

- The `issuer` on issuing.
- The `holder` on moving.
- The `issuer` and `holder` on redeeming.

But also the contract says [here](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/ad257bda46028d370da49f1de75a6eb2eb3adfcc/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/contracts/FungibleTokenContract.kt#L55) that there could be other signers on issue; so I'm not 100% sure that's the cause of the problem.
Try removing the signature flows and re-run your test; and let me know if it worked.
Another thing, check the logs of the initiating node (the log is inside `logs` folder inside your node's folder structure); are there any errors?.

Comment: thx for "remove CollectSignaturesFlow  and  responder's SignTransactionFlow "  Works for me!